# Simple addition of two numbers on Atmega328P simulation on Proteus

Tags: microcontroller, atmega

I'm new to simulation on Proteus using microcontroller. All the online beginners tutorial show how to flash LEDs using microcontrollers, I'm just curious cannot we just add two numbers and get the result as output without involving any LED?
Should I just write the adding integers code in C, convert to hex file and load it on ATMEGA328 ?  Where (any particular port of the microcontroller) will I see the output? Do I need to specify that in that C code? Please guide me! And also any link doing this kindof stuff would be very helpful.Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I think this question is wrong,Please provide enough details

1. Controller (AVR/PIC/ARM/TI)
2. 8-bit/16-bit/32-bit
3. Compiler/IDE

In micro controllers you write any port(GPIO) and check your output.

If you don't want to see output with any output device led,7-segment,LCD display and etc then just write port directly and find your answer.

```
int main()
{
   int x=10,y=20;
   SET_PORT_DIRECTION   = OUTPUT;
   YOUR_CONTROLLER_PORT = x+y;
   while(1); 
}
```

In Proteus you will find which one YOUR_PORT led is on or off accordingly your output

### if you used 8bit Microcontroller

---

You will able to write MAX Value 255 to the single port(in case of 8-bit micro controller)

X = 10, Y=20;

Then X+Y = 30;

HEX VALUE of 30 : 0x1E;

YOUR_PORT(8 bit) = 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;

YOUR_PORT        = x+y;

YOUR_PORT        = 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0;

In Proteus

```
      PORT_LED on/OFF :

                   LHB :  
                         PIN : 0       STATE: OFF 
                         PIN : 1       STATE: ON   
                         PIN : 2       STATE: ON
                         PIN : 3       STATE: ON
                         PIN : 4       STATE: ON
                         PIN : 5       STATE: OFF
                         PIN : 6       STATE: OFF
                         PIN : 7       STATE: OFF
```

and also just used Digital Multi meter to check voltage on controller pins and check your answers.

Comment: Thanks bhura112.  I was trying to interface LCD (16X2 )alphanumeric display LM016L to Atmega32, I have loaded the compiled hex file, but the LCD remains bright green glowing without showing anything. I can see the ports getting input/output by changing color from red to blue dots , does it mean there is some problem, or the input is not reaching the LCD?

Comment: check out video link interfacing lcd 16x2 with avr micro controller https://youtu.be/f9U4FZ9njm8 and also visit http://www.sembedded.net for code and proteus design